# I am getting a nan error when doing loops

Tags: loops, nan

So, I am using xcode on mac and made a program that basically does simple math with the users entered values and keeps looping unless it is interrupted. At the end of the loop (once it is broken) I want to print out the total average value (so do some more math). I use a counter and sum variables to do this. However, in out output, I am getting a "nan" error when the loop end and the overall average has to display. Can anyone help, please? :/

int main() {

```
double gallons=0;
double miles=0;
double sum=0;
int count=0;

while (gallons>=0) {

    sum+=(miles/gallons);
    count++;

    printf("\nEnter the gallons used (-1 to end): ");
    scanf("%lf",&gallons);

    if (gallons<0)
        break;

    printf("Enter the miles driven: ");
    scanf("%lf",&miles);

    if (miles<0)
        break;

    printf("The miles/gallon for this tank was: %lf", miles/gallons);

}

if (gallons<0) {

    printf("The average is: %lf", sum/(count-1));
}

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double gallons=0;
double miles=0;
…
sum+=(miles/gallons);
```

Dividing zero by zero produces a NaN. Once there is a NaN, any arithmetic with it also produces a NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. In first iteration in `sum+=(miles/gallons);` you try to add to `sum` value `0/0`. So, I think that you need to move this addition **after** inputs. Something like

```
printf("\nEnter the gallons used (-1 to end): ");
scanf("%lf",&gallons);

if (gallons<0)
    break;

printf("Enter the miles driven: ");
scanf("%lf",&miles);

if (miles<0)
    break;

printf("The miles/gallon for this tank was: %lf", miles/gallons);
sum+=(miles/gallons);
count++;
```